# Wordpress how to order by order input value

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-admin

When you create a post in Wordpress, there's a field called "order".

How can i make it work to for example, i put `5` and the post goes to the `5th` position when displayed on the page?

I tried this but didn't work:

```
<?php
            $args = array(
               'post_type' => 'team',
               'posts_per_page' => 30,
               'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
               'order' => 'ASC'
            );
            $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
            if ($the_query->have_posts()) : while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
            ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the post is saved, WordPress takes the value from the "order" field and saves it to the wp_posts.menu_order column within the database. With that being said, you'll want to set the "orderby" parameter to "menu_order".

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'team',
  'posts_per_page' => 30,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'order' => 'ASC'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If "order" is a custom field, then you could do something like this:

```php
$the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'team',
    'posts_per_page' => 30,
    'meta_key' => 'order',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
  ));
```

Let me know if it works for you!